# Effects processor: Thoughts about software architecture, choice of programming language, API

Tags: architecture, signal-processing, real-time, low-latency, jack

I'm currently working on a project where a major element is a piece of software that can do signal processing in real-time.

The basic idea/concept is the following. Audio data is captured continuously from a (USB) audio interface (running at 96 kHz, 24 bit). It is then run through a "processing chain" (like a "virtual effects chain"), where each element can perform arbitrary processing on the data. The data is handed from one element to the next, until it arrives at a sink. Data which flows into the sink is sent back to the audio interface for output.

The signal chain consists of "objects" that implement some "processing" method, which works on chunks of data of 1920 samples (20 ms) size (though one might change this number).

The basic idea in "pseudo code".

```
while (true) {
   float[] samples = audio.read(BLOCK_SIZE);

   foreach (Effect e in signal_flow)
      e.process(samples);

   audio.write(samples);
}
```

A first prototype has been implemented in Python which uses the ALSA API for audio I/O. Three separate threads are started.

The first one is continuously reading from ALSA (which is a blocking operation) and puts the data into a queue, then goes on with reading the next block. (ALSA requires me to "read(...)" at least every 20 ms, so I need a very lightweight thread for that, which does nothing but read and store data, so I can meet my time constraints.)

The second one reads the samples from the input from this queue, puts them through the signal chain and finally into another queue for output.

The third thread reads from this output queue (which is a blocking operation) and writes the blocks out to ALSA.

I basically have two "numeric" variables here, one being the block size and the other being the number of blocks that I "pre-post" to the output queue before I even begin processing, which gives me some time to "deliver more samples" without the output buffer underrunning. In addition, I can decide to do these things either in separate threads or in separate processes.

After some serious debugging (which involved the use of both a signal generator and an oscilloscope!), I finally got this approach running. The biggest problem was a bug in the ALSA API, namely that "period_size", which is specified as "the number of **frames** that are read/written" appears to actually be the number of **frames** read, but the number of **bytes** written. When I specify 1920 (20 ms of audio at 96 kHz sampling rate) for both, input and output, I get only 1/4 of output, then 3/4 of silence, then 1/4 of output. When I specify 1920 * 4 = 7680 for both, input and output, I get an error that the device's buffer is not large enough to read this many frames. When I specify 1920 for input and 7680 for output, it works perfectly (and my queues do not "overfill" either).

Having that solved, I have one serious problem left and that is: Latency!

I basically started this entire project in order to create my own effects, so I want this software to operate as an effects unit for stage/live use. I've read that when two events are less than 30 ms apart, e. g. two strobe lights are fired 30 ms apart, the human brain can no longer tell which one was first and which was second. So a delay of 30 ms or less would basically be percieved as "instant". It's the threshold where events "merge" and are percieved as "one". If the latency were that low, you couldn't tell which event is first, so e. g. a guitarist could no longer tell, if he struck the string and then sound came from the PA or if sound came from the PA and then he struck the string, so it would basically feel like "zero latency" and thus like a real amp.

Now the latency I have currently arrived at is ... well ... I didn't have the opportunity to exactly measure them yet, but it's in the order of tenths of a second, say 200 or 300 ms. It's far too much! I tried both separate threads and processes for the I/O (since in Python you never know if threads are really gonna be faster due to the "global interpreter lock") and processes were significantly slower, which was to be expected, due to the overhead associated with inter-process communication and the fact that the two I/O processes don't do anything "intensive". They just wait on blocking operations and perform fast I/O.

As another remark, I would like to say that I want my application to host a web server (of course in a separate thread or even process) to allow the user to configure the signal path and adjust the parameters for the effects "devices" in an intuitive way.

So obviously I need to get latency down! I have several paths to follow now.

1. My first idea is to replace ALSA with JACK, which is said to be "low-latency". Drawbacks are that I lose control over the exact levels at the ADC/DAC (JACK always works with floats, which are already scaled to [-1.0, 1.0], no matter what the hardware does) and over sampling rate (as far as I know, JACK "dictates" a sampling rate - I can no longer chose - with ALSA I could select a sampling rate I want to work with and it would transparently upsample/downsample for me if the hardware deviated from that), that the blocking I/O (that I find a pretty nice paradigm) is replaced with a callback mechanism and that timing constraints are probably much harder to meet. (I cannot "buffer" on my own with JACK. It always requires processing to be done in a certain amount of time.) Also, the JACK API appears to be more complicated in general, than the ALSA API. I could probably replace ALSA with JACK, but I'm not sure how much I could "win", given that ALSA is already a pretty "low-level" API and JACK builds upon, but probably uses in a very specific way to keep latencies low. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure just how much of that latency is due to ALSA and "below" and how much is due to "higher layers".
2. I currently make use of an interpreted, garbage-collected language. That's bad for real-time requirements. But what are the alternatives? Well, of course C comes to mind when thinking about real-time applications, but there are serious drawbacks.

2.1 - I want the software to have a web-based UI. Creating a web server in Python is simple. There's a class for it in the Python standard library. Creating a web server in C is a pain. There's basically NOTHING in C that could do "web". I'll have to start from scratch based on nothing but a socket API. Good luck! :-(

2.2 - Python has support for numerics. It has numpy and scipy and therefore vector data types, matrix multiplication, fast fourier transform, fast convolution, interpolation (splines, etc.). This is all very useful for the problem at hand here. In C, I lose all this, which means I either have to get the job done without, which is very unlikely, or I'll have to recreate all of this on my own in C, which is both time-consuming and error-prone.

2.3 - Python has "high-level" support for multiprocessing and multithreading. I can communicate between processes and threads via synchronized queues, implementing my solution in a "thread pool / replicated workers"-style fashion, which is an **extremely** useful paradigm for the problem at hand here. In C, I'll have to resort to POSIX threads and low-level synchronization primitives like mutices. (Is that the correct plural for "mutex"? Like in "Unix" --> "Unices"?) Again, this is both time-consuming and error-prone.

Any suggestions on which languages to use? Languages I'm familiar with include Python, C-Sharp, Java, C, Go, a **little bit** of C++ (I never need that language - either it's low-level, then I use C, or it's high-level, then I use a garbage-collected, interpreter or bytecode-compiled language), and some web technologies (especially JavaScript with AJAX, etc., which will be useful when it comes to the UI).

All of this **has to** run under a Linux distribution, preferably with as little dependencies / libraries as possible. "Standard" libraries are thus preferred over "exotic" ones. Platform-independance, especially the ability to also run under Windows, is a plus, but not strictly a requirement.

I'm ok with the UI being implemented in a different language (Go for the web server comes to mind) than the actual processing (which **might** "have to be done in C" if it needs to be real-time?), though this brings a lot of extra complexity, as both will then run in separate processes and communicate via, say, Unix Domain Sockets, which requires all data to be passed back and forth to be represented as a byte stream (since that's all a socket transports), so one needs to design an inter-process communication protocol and do lots of parsing at this level as well. Any chance to avoid this huge overhead and do it in a single language?

Any other ideas? Specifically, will I gain anything by going from ALSA to JACK? Are there other alternatives I haven't considered yet, which might suit the task even better?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Your question is a little to broad for this format.  However, here are some generic suggestions for a real-time audio software architecture: Consider using 2 programming languages, a compiled non-GC language (C or Swift) for all the near-real-time sample processing code, and possibly another, possibly interpreted, language (Python or JS) for the UI.  Use buffers that are much shorter than 20 mS.  Use a callback-based API, as that usually requires less buffering (added latency) than a threaded model.

Comment: I stopped at 'A first prototype has been implemented in Python'

Comment: @MartinJames Your attention span seems to be a bit low. Unfortunately, this appears to be pretty common these days. I understand this is a lot of information. However, in my opinion, it makes sense to share everything I've tried and all the ideas I have. Otherwise I might get trivial answers or "solutions", telling me to do what is already done or to consider things I already considered. My problem is pretty specific, so I have to be very specific describing it.